# $(document).ready + jQuery + understand

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand `$(document).ready` with this, perhaps, silly [JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/n7ekvjqc/1/) (this basically uses jQuery to draw 10 divs with a title Graph1...) There is numerous question on this already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963645/document-ready-clarification) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657572/jquery-document-ready). But what i want is to understand the flow/order of how this works, relative to the DOM..etc. Why I should use it and why I should not. I am trying to use this silly example to understand it better

Specifically, with the jsfiddle example, Why does it not work with `noWrap - in <body>` and `$(document).ready(function(){` is commented out?

**Note:** Maybe this example is too silly or unclear to wha I want, but with your comments I will hopefully be able to clarify it and get a better understanding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Access Links</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- <script src="../src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!-- works here with $(document).ready(function(){ commented out  -->
    <!-- DOES NOT WORK here with $(document).ready(function(){  -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- <script src="../src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!-- works here with $(document).ready(function(){ commented out  -->
    <!-- DOES NOT WORK here with $(document).ready(function(){  -->
        <div class="container" id="graphs">
        <!-- My divs will go here -->
        </div>
    <!-- <script src="../src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!-- works here with $(document).ready(function(){ commented out  -->
    <!-- DOES NOT WORK here with $(document).ready(function(){  --> 
        <script>
        //$(document).ready(function(){
        //--------- START: Draw all your divs------------------------------------------>
        var numberOfDivs =10; 
        for (var x = 1; x <= numberOfDivs; x += 1) {
        var $div = $('<div class="chart half"><h3 id="g' + x + '">Graph' + x + '</h3><svg id="chart' + x + '"></svg></div>');
            $('#graphs').append($div);
        }
        //--------- END: Draw all your divs------------------------------------------>
        //}
        </script>
        <!-- <script src="../src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- DOES NOT work here with $(document).ready(function(){ commented out  -->
        <!-- DOES NOT WORK here with $(document).ready(function(){  -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code sample's comments make the comparisons of "working" from "not working" quite difficult to follow.  I would fully expect the sample posted to work as designed without using `$(document).ready()` since the elements are referenced after they're created in the DOM.

Comment: @David tks,but Maybe you can answer the specific Q i asked re the js fiddle example as a starter

Comment: And what *is* your specific question?  That's my point, what you're asking is unclear.  When to use `$(document).ready()`?  Well, you'd use it when you don't want your code to execute until the document's `ready` event, which is invoked when the DOM is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the function $(document).ready,I recommended you read the source code of jQuery.Like this:

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) )
    return jQuery( document ).ready( selector );
```

if the selector is a function in $(), the $(document).ready will work.BTW,I guess you want to know the execution time of this function,this function will work when the DOM tree is loaded complete.